# React Native - Turn off audio playing in background after certain time

Tags: android, ios, react-native, timer, background-audio

I went through every possible resource to find a way to stop the audio play in background.

```
setTimeout(() => {

   //Turn off the music
   console.log('TURNING OFF MUSIC AFTER 4 MINS');

}, 240000);
```

**Case 1: iOS**
Playing audio, app is put into background and even if the screen is locked , timer method turns off my music .

**Case 2: Android**
Playing audio and app put to background , even if I set time to 30 seconds , above timeout  function body is not fired.

**For iOS**, I got background mode turned on in capabilities in xcode. May be for that reason , setTimeout() method is working fine for me.

But in case of android , I am not able to think of a solution.

Any Solutions !!

I saw that background timer modules but I think if setTimeout() works for ios then why not for android. May be somebody has another idea.

**UPDATE**
Can I turn off the music playing in background using local notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the only option using the background timer.

[Background Timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer)

Hope it helps !!